# Problem building release-v0.16

Tags: source, build

I can build release-v0.15 perfectly.
However, when I change to branch v0.16 and try to build it, it failed every time.
Can anyone give me some advice to solve it? Thanks!

```
[ 36%] Building CXX object src/checkpoints/CMakeFiles/obj_checkpoints.dir/checkpoints.cpp.o
/media/test/monero/src/checkpoints/checkpoints.cpp: In member function ‘uint64_t cryptonote::checkpoints::get_max_height() const’:
/media/test/monero/src/checkpoints/checkpoints.cpp:138:103: error: ‘boost::placeholders’ has not been declared
                          ( boost::bind(&std::map< uint64_t, crypto::hash >::value_type::first, boost::placeholders::_1) <
                                                                                                       ^
/media/test/monero/src/checkpoints/checkpoints.cpp:139:103: error: ‘boost::placeholders’ has not been declared
                            boost::bind(&std::map< uint64_t, crypto::hash >::value_type::first, boost::placeholders::_2 ) ) );
                                                                                                       ^
src/checkpoints/CMakeFiles/obj_checkpoints.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'src/checkpoints/CMakeFiles/obj_checkpoints.dir/checkpoints.cpp.o' failed
make[3]: *** [src/checkpoints/CMakeFiles/obj_checkpoints.dir/checkpoints.cpp.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/media/test/monero/build/Linux/release-v0.16/release'
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1241: recipe for target 'src/checkpoints/CMakeFiles/obj_checkpoints.dir/all' failed
make[2]: *** [src/checkpoints/CMakeFiles/obj_checkpoints.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/media/test/monero/build/Linux/release-v0.16/release'
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/media/test/monero/build/Linux/release-v0.16/release'
Makefile:102: recipe for target 'release-all' failed
make: *** [release-all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either need to upgrade boost or use this PR: https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/6612

An earlier PR got merged that broke boost compatibility.

Comment: Okay. `git checkout release-v0.16 && git fetch origin pull/6612/head:pr-6612 && git rebase pr-6612` does the trick :)